# Matlab is printing comments and other contents of a script to command window

Tags: matlab

Below is a script in which I sum elements of a vector.
My problem here is that whenever I run the script, Matlab prints *everything* onto the command window. That is, it prints the comments, and everything else.

I only wanted to print the sum as an output, that is why I did not put `;` after `y = sum(x)`.

Can somebody help me prevent Matlab from printing the comments and contents of the script, except the ones I only want to print? Below is the script

```
%simple script
%this script sums the number of elements in a vector.
x = 1:2:10;
y  = sum(x)
```

Here is the output in command window
[image: output]

Comment: How do you run the script ? btw, you did put a ";" after `y = sum(x)`

Comment: am sorry I just edited it. I just hit the green triangular button in Matlab to run the script

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run the script by pressing F5 ?

Comment: I had never seen that behaviour, and I definitely can't reproduce it with the information you provide. Did you try restarting Matlab?

Comment: @LuisMendo, Thank you I just restarted Matlab and problem solved. Wow I was never expecting a program like Matlab to glitch. Also G.J thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Raykh It's no glitch, probably; see Andras' great answer

Answer (score 7):

Apparently [`echo on`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/echo.html) has been set in your MATLAB. You need to turn it off:

```
>> echo off
```

Comment: @Raykh it's been set before you run the script. Either manually, or in some startup script/default setting. Try issuing `echo off` manually, and running your script again. You should stop seeing that output.

Comment: It may have been typed in your Matlab session, perhaps inadvertently

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks guys, I appreciate your answers.